# What do PY, L, and E mean on the label of this olive oil product?

Tags: italian-cuisine, olive-oil

[image: back of bottle showing Chinese text and info described below]

[image: front of bottle]

On the back of Filippo Berio extra virgin olive oil,

- PY20/21
- L2022.03.28
- E2024.03.28

What do the first two mean?

How do the three tell the quality of the oil?

Answer (score 32):

I read these as

- PY20/21
  Production year 2020/2021 - or harvest season, which is typically between October and February, but may vary.
- L2022.03.28
  Label date, probably also when the oil was bottled.
- E2024.03.28
  “Expiry” date, two years after the label date. Note that you should interpret this rather as a best-before date and a quality degradation indicator, not a food safety indicator.

The numbers don’t tell you anything about the quality of the oil per se (considering you previous questions), but after two years, or rather three, considering the first date, there may be some degradation, which may or may not be noticeable, depending on different factors (e.g. storage conditions).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151763/discussion-on-answer-by-stephie-what-do-these-mean-on-the-label-of-this-olive-oi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Because the comments on other answers have been moved, I am supplying a supplementary answer which addresses the "quality" portion of the question.

Elsewhere on the label you will see:

> Packed in Italy with oils from Greece, Italy, Portugal, Spain

This is what's called a "blended" olive oil, which is usually an indicator of lower quality.  This is because, while sometimes oil distributors blend to maintain a taste profile, most of the time they do it to lower costs, using whatever are the cheapest available oils.  Industry-wide, that includes adding things that [aren't olive oil at all](https://www.oliveoiltimes.com/grades/main-types-of-olive-oil-fraud-revealed/91799).  Filippo Berio in particular is [known for doing this](https://www.oliveoiltimes.com/business/north-america/filippo-berio-and-bertolli-class-action/45953).

Comment: Thanks! What brands of evoo would you recommend which are also not expensive? Sam club's member Mark,  la espanola, MUELOLIVA, betis, and more  are also available in PDD

Comment: So, real virgin olive oil is going to be expensive right now, period.  There's a global shortage due to the failure of the olive crop in Spain.  If you find anything that's less than $12USD/liter it's certainly fake; expect to pay more like $20/L.  Member's Mark is another blended olive oil, made mostly from olive pomace oil.  Sam's Club's Ommagio (glass bottle) has a much better reputation.  I am not familiar with the other brands.

Comment: But ... all the other brands you mention are Spanish.  Even if, in a normal year, they're trustworthy, I'd be extra-skeptical of anything reasonably priced from Spain this year.

Comment: For taste, favorites are Colavita (Italy) and Terra Delyssa (Tunisia - square bottle, yellow label with horse).